# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud' even though I installed it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-cloud-vision, modulenotfounderror

I want to use the vision api and I just started with the imports. I am getting the message I pasted in the title when I run the code, so far I tried to `pip install google-cloud` which should I believe be all I need to do. I am using python 3.6.2, pip 20.3.3 and windows 10 64bit. I am using a virtual environment. This is my code so far, as I mentioned these are just imports:

```
import os, io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

and I am failing at line 2.

edit: my bad, fixed by creating and downloading a key on the google website, you better read the installation constructions completely if you had the same problem! `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=apikey.json` oh yeah you should cd into the directory of the key file, or include the path of the file.

Comment: Did you follow the exact official installation instructions, including using the `virtualenv` related commands? https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/

Comment: Well I did "pip install virtualenv"
and I created a virtualenv named venv using "virtualenv venv"

Then I used "C:\Users\user\venv\Scripts\activate" to activate the virtualenv

and finally I did
"C:\Users\Linus\venv\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-vision"

and I create a .py file in the venv folder using the same code, getting the same error message. Is the venv folder the right location?

Comment: How are you running the script? If you run `python scriptname.py` in the command line does that cause the same issue? Are you sure that you're using that virtual environment to run the script? I'd take a look at this and see if you're missing any steps, I'm not really familiar with virtualenv personally: https://dev.to/ngazetungue/python-script-in-virtual-environment-beginners-guide-h6d

Comment: I just followed the guide by making a new virtual environment but I realized that whenever I create a file I am missing out the bin and the lib64 folders and I have no idea why

Comment: I think that warrants a separate question specific to that issue.

Comment: My bad, I edited everything, sorry for taking your time with such an error..

Comment: No worries, also you can post an answer to your own question and accept that, rather than just editing the question to say it's solved.

Comment: ok, I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

my bad, fixed by creating and downloading a key on the google website, you better read the installation constructions completely if you had the same problem! set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=apikey.json oh yeah you should cd into the directory of the key file, or include the path of the file.